# Simple animations of TextBlock and Grid controls

Tags: visual-c++, windows-store-apps

My goal is to do simple animations (es fadeIn, fadeOut) of a TextBlock for example.
How can I do it? I searched some explanation but I found them very very complicated, talking about scenarios, ecc. I would know if it can be more simple, or if someone can give me a simple explanation of the procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should give you an idea how to do it (the duration could be reduced if it's too slow for you)
This is the Xaml:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="FadeOutStoryboard">
            <!-- This animation will animate the value of the Canvas.Left property of the rectangle Scenario1Rectangle to 300. -->
            <DoubleAnimation 
        Storyboard.TargetName="txtToFade" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
        Duration="0:0:1" 
        To="0" 
        />
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="FadeInStoryboard">
            <!-- This animation will animate the value of the Canvas.Left property of the rectangle Scenario1Rectangle to 300. -->
            <DoubleAnimation 
        Storyboard.TargetName="txtToFade" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
        Duration="0:0:1" 
        To="1" 
        />
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Name="txtToFade"></TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And in the code behind this is how you execute the storyboards:-

```
 FadeOutStoryboard->Begin();
```

or

```
 FadeInStoryboard->Begin();
```

You can use the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.aspx) to control the animations based on events (such as mouse over etc).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the animation sample at this location?

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Animations-f758de70

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried this sample: it isn't what I need because it talks about movement animations and storyboards. I just need a fadein, fadeout effect for the menu of my app.